# unable to post minute, hour works

Tags: php, html, mysql

i'm stuck here and would appreciate some guidance, not just the answer, but how I could trouble shoot by placing "traps" to see where it's going wrong.
The main problem is I can't get "minute" to be posted, the mysql update puts nothing for minute.  "Hour" works.
 I had a var_dump($_POST) in there to see what's being posted , for minute nothing is being posted and I don't know why since I'm doing similar method for minute as for hour, and hour works.
Please help.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once "db.php";

if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && $_POST["submit"]!="") {
// var_dump($_POST); 
$usersCount = count($_POST["hour"]);
for($i=0;$i<$usersCount;$i++) {
mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE events set hour='" . $_POST["hour"][$i] . "', minute='" . $_POST["minute"][$i] . "'   WHERE event='" . $_POST["event"][$i] . "'");
}
// header("Location:golist.php");
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Edit events</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
<form name="frmUser" method="post" action="">
<div style="width:500px;">
<table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="500" align="center">
<tr class="tableheader">
<td>Edit Event</td>
</tr>
<?php
$rowCount = count($_POST["myevents"]);
// var_dump($_POST);
for($i=0;$i<$rowCount;$i++) {
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM events  WHERE event='" . $_POST["myevents"][$i] . "'");
$row[$i]= mysqli_fetch_array($result);
// $CompanyID=$row["id"];
?>
<tr>
 <td>
  <table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="500" align="center" class="tblSaveForm">
   <tr>
    <td><label>Hour</label></td>
    <td><input type="hidden"  class="txtField" name="event[]"  value="<?php echo $row[$i]['event']; ?>">  
    <form><select name="hour[]">
    <option><?php echo $row[$i]['hour']; ?></option>
    <option value="00">00</option>
    <option value="01">01</option>
    <option value="02">02</option>
    </select>
    </form>
    </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td><label for="minute">Minute</label></td>
    <td><input type="hidden"  class="txtField" name="event[]"  value="<?php echo  $row[$i]['event']; ?>">
    <form><select name="minute[]">
    <option><?php echo $row[$i]['minute']; ?></option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="45">45</option>
    </select>
    </form>
    </td>
   </tr>

</table>
</td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btnSubmit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>
</body></html>
```

Comment: thanks for the comment but it doesn't help me at the moment, this is a closed system and I'm trying to learn the basics first.

Comment: Prepared statements are the basics and they are easier than what you are currently doing.

Comment: can you please point me to something where there are drop down menu in html ?   In case you haven't noticed, I'm not really a software person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have hours and minutes and your button in separate forms. Move your form statement before the table starts and remove the 2nd one and the closing form tags.

To address the vulnerability Dharman mentions you'll also want to use prepared statements.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once "db.php";

if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && $_POST["submit"]!="") {
    // var_dump($_POST);
    $usersCount = count($_POST["hour"]);
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE events SET hour = ? , minute= ?');
    for($i=0;$i<$usersCount;$i++) {
        $stmt->bind_param("ss",$_POST["hour"][$i],$_POST["minute"][$i]);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
    // header("Location:golist.php");
}
?>

<form name="frmUser" method="post" action="">
<div style="width:500px;">
<table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="500" align="center">
<tr class="tableheader">
<td>Edit Event</td>
</tr>
<?php
$rowCount = count($_POST["myevents"]);
// var_dump($_POST);
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM events  WHERE event= ?');
for($i=0;$i<$rowCount;$i++) {
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$_POST["myevents"][$i]);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row[$i] = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_array();
// $CompanyID=$row["id"];
?>
<tr>
 <td>
  <table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="500" align="center" class="tblSaveForm">
   <tr>
    <td><label>Hour</label></td>
    <td><input type="hidden"  class="txtField" name="event[]"  value="<?php echo $row[$i]['event']; ?>">
    <select name="hour[]">
    <option><?php echo $row[$i]['hour']; ?></option>
    <option value="00">00</option>
    <option value="01">01</option>
    <option value="02">02</option>
    </select>
    </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td><label for="minute">Minute</label></td>
    <td><input type="hidden"  class="txtField" name="event[]"  value="<?php echo  $row[$i]['event']; ?>">
    <select name="minute[]">
    <option><?php echo $row[$i]['minute']; ?></option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="45">45</option>
    </select>
    </td>
   </tr>

</table>
</td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btnSubmit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>
</body></html>
```